# Volume of $y = 6\sqrt{\sin(x)}$ rotated around $y$-axis using triple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

The problem is to find the volume of $y = 6\cdot \sqrt{\sin (x)}$ rotated around the $y$-axis when $0 \leq y \leq 6$.

I know this can be done by the sv-calc method of volumes of revolution but I wanted to see if a problem like this can be done by triple integrals. I tried it a few times myself but could not seem to get the limits of the integrals set up correctly.

Comment: Visualize the object.  Then decide on an order of integration.  I would suggest integrating the $z$ variable first so that we can get the $z$ axis out of the way and return to the $xy$ plane.  To set up the bounds for the $z$ variable, ask yourself: "What two surfaces does the volume lie between?"

Comment: I'm not sure this can actually be done. I end up with the integral $\int_{0}^{6} \int_{0}^{arcsin(y^2/36)}\int_{0}^{2\pi }rd\Theta drdy$ which I can't find a way to solve.

Comment: Hmm... what if you integrate the $y$ variable first?

Comment: You can use polar coordination. Solution in any other coordination is somehow similar to that just with a different representation.

Comment: Did you say there was a second method that worked ? Would you mind giving a reference to it ? Thanks.

Comment: After some work, I got:

$\int_0^{2\pi}$$\int_0^{arcsin(\frac{r^2(sin^2(\theta))}{36})}$$\int_0^6$$rdydrd\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I miss the point of your question, but I think that the rotation of a function $y=f(x)$ around the $y$-axis using the formula
\begin{align*}
V=\pi\int_a^bx^2(y) dy\tag{1}
\end{align*}
and your Ansatz in the comment using a triple integral is essentially the same.

> Since for
>
> \begin{align*}
> y=6\sqrt{\sin (x)}\qquad\longleftrightarrow\qquad x=\arcsin\left(\frac{y^2}{36}\right)
> \end{align*}
>   We observe according to your comment
>   \begin{align*}
> &\int_0^6\int_0^{\arcsin(\frac{y^2}{36})}\int_0^{2\pi}r d\Theta dr dy\\
> &\qquad=\int_0^6\int_0^{\arcsin(\frac{y^2}{36})}\left. r\cdot\Theta\right|_0^{2\pi} dr dy\\
> &\qquad=2\pi\int_0^6\int_0^{\arcsin(\frac{y^2}{36})}r dr dy\\
> &\qquad=2\pi\int_0^6\left.\left(\frac{1}{2}r^2\right)\right|_0^{\arcsin(\frac{y^2}{36})}dy\\
> &\qquad=\pi\int_0^6\arcsin^2\left(\frac{y^2}{36}\right)dy\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> and (2) corresponds to the volume formula (1).

I think the difficulty lies in solving the integral (2) which seems to allow no simple closed representation. Wolfram alpha provides following solution:

> \begin{align*}
> &\pi\int\arcsin^2\left(\frac{y^2}{36}\right)dy\\
> &\qquad=\frac{\pi^2y^5}{5184\sqrt{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)}
> _{3}F_{2}\left(1,\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{7}{4},\frac{9}{4};\left(\frac{y}{6}\right)^4\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad-\frac{2\pi y}{3} _2F_1\left(1,\frac{5}{4};\frac{7}{4};\left(\frac{y}{6}\right)^4\right)
> \arcsin\left(\frac{y^2}{36}\right)\sin\left(2\arcsin\left(\frac{y^2}{36}\right)\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\pi y\arcsin^2\left(\frac{y^2}{36}\right)+C
> \end{align*}

*Note:* You could perform a plausibility check, take a simpler integrand and you'll be able to calculate the volume in both ways.

Comment: @JakeLebovic: That's high speed, Jake! Thanks for granting the bounty! :-)